# node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-59\binding.node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: webpack, sass-loader

I am getting this weird node-sass error when my webpack is building an app. It does not happen in the console it happens in the compiled file.

https://paste.laravel.io/b9d2883d-8c12-4309-aafb-d151bc5edea6

In my entry point, there is only one line `console.log('test')` which executes but then in the there is this unknown module second module that is being generated that is throwing an error.

Here is my webpack config.

https://paste.laravel.io/721cb01c-445b-41c6-8fc3-57e4359b496f

utils file has just small helper

```
const path = require('path')

exports.resolve = function(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '../../../', dir)
}

exports.assetsPath = function(_path) {
  return path.join('/', _path)
}
```

I don't understand whats happening as inside terminal everything compiles without a single error, then browser throws this stupid exception. I have tried already rebuilding modules but it doesn't help.

Could someone please help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Guys just ignore this thread I am just being stupid here. My entry point was main.js, I was loading app.js for some reason it worked but with an error that I described above. After changing it to main.js things started to work. Thanks anyway